# Querying Firestore for a specific set of IDs

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a bunch of documents in the `Users` collection and they all have a `localUserId` key and a `Bool` called `isOnline`, how can I query Firestore for only documents within a set of `localUserIds` where `isOnline = true`

```
let localUserIds = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]

let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.collection("Users")
   .whereField("localUserId", ???: localUserIds) // this is the unknown part
   .whereField("isOnline", isEqualTo: true)
   .getDocuments { snapshot, error in 
       ...
   }
```

Comment: Make multiple queries, one for each document.  There's no query by array in the client SDKs, just in the server SDK.

Comment: Let's say I have 250k users, it's not feasible to query each one. It's slightly more feasible (but not by much) to query all `Users` where `isOnline = true` and then filter for `localUserId`. Is queryByArray planned for clientSDKs anytime soon? Thanks Doug

Comment: It is feasible to query each one individually.

Comment: Really? Maybe I underestimated Firestore :)

Comment: If you have a problem, post again explaining what's not working the way you expect.